# Can't get Changes tool window (Alt+9) to show on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I can't get the Changes tool window to show on this project.
The project is imported "from sources" and has no facet and no sdk. Which is ok because I'm only editing it in the IDE and running from the terminal.

I'm on Windows 8.
The tool window does show when I open another java web maven project there.
It also does show for the first (no sdk) project when I'm on Ubuntu.

What might the Changes tool window not like about my project?

Answer (score 2):

The IDE wasn't aware of Git in my project.
That happened because the directory I import this project from isn't the same as the Git repository directory, the former is inside the later.

I fixed it in: VCS > Enable Version Control Integration